# Is Agora's unity plugin capable of 360 VR video calls?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, videochat, agora.io

is it possible to make a video call, in 360 format, and have it come out on the receiving end as a 360 video still within the Unity plugin?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible if you apply the 360 video stream to an inverted sphere and place the VR camera inside the sphere.

Comment: This isn't an answer it is a guess. I know you can't make comments yet so I am going up-vote this. Then you will have enough rep to comment. Please change it to a comment and then delete this answer that isn't an answer... or test and confirm that it works and make it an answer instead of a guess. :-)